# Java spring uploading a photand creating a new jsp with this photo

Tags: java, spring

I am starting to learn Spring. I am using Spring Boot. I'v created a form by which I can upload a photo to the server. After that I want that so my app generate a random link with that photo. What is it called? Where should I look for infos about it ?

Comment: what do you mean by a random link?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20907133/how-to-display-uploaded-images-in-spring-mvc-application

Comment: You know, a good example is an imageshack.us, where you upload a photo and generate a random link for it.

Comment: 9gag is good example aswell